# Python: Scanning raw_input

Tags: python

I would like to get multiple commands from raw_input(). I have been using this:

```
reply = raw_input(">").split(' ')

command = reply[0]

file = reply[1]
```

but this seems very hacky to me is there a better way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the most pythonic way is

```
command,file = raw_input(">").split()
```

using tuple unpacking instead of indexing

In Python3.0+, you may use

```
command,file,*everything_else = raw_input(">").split()#untested
```

Comment: This assumes there are only 2 items in raw_input(">").split(' ')

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly acceptable way of reading multiple commands. There isn't really a way to do it without using split. The only thing you have to be careful of is that spaces can *only* delineate the end of an argument, since it will split on any space.

Edit: If you're having problems with multiple spaces, use `split()` instead of `split(' ')`. That will take multiple whitespaces as one split.

Comment: Yes I noticed that if I hit a double space it throws an error. I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: If you notice in my response above, its easier to use .split() instead of .split(' ') because .split() will split on any whitespace, but may also be an issue.

Comment: Yup saw that and have tested it just waiting to except :)